# Some StackExchange sites are differ from other SE sites

Tags: support, stack-exchange

Some of the Stack Exchange sites like [Superuser](https://superuser.com/),[ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)  didn't have `stackexchange.com` in their urls, whereas someother sites like https://android.stackexchange.com/ , https://apple.stackexchange.com/ had unique themes of their own , but some other sites like https://sports.stackexchange.com/ didn't had it.

Recently, I saw another thing like

[image]
`Stack Exchange` was added to the names of site which were didn't having their unique themes.

I can understand that the SU and SF are the oldest and more busy SE sites, and sites like sports, christianity are with less users and low traffic. But I need to know, **When can a SE site have its own theme and its own url like SU?**

Comment: They are still Beta sites.

Comment: @Bart, 'They' include http://android.stackexchange.com/ and http://apple.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: No, the circled sites without a unique theme

Comment: @Bart, ok my qn is 'When can a SE site have its own theme and its own url like SU?'

Comment: It will usually get its own theme once out of beta afaik. The URL will probably remain an SE one.

Comment: @Bart, then how did SU and SF had their own url? pls, eloborate ur ans

Comment: They are part of the original [Stack Overflow trilogy of sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/). I am not fully aware of the historical details, but I assume this is pre-Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Bart - The trilogy predates Area51, that's why they are so "different".